# Is it possible to register services in Avalonia?

Tags: avaloniaui, avalonia

Does Avalonia UI have the ability to register its services in the Program class or do I have to connect third party MVVM support libraries?

```
public static void Main(string[] args) => BuildAvaloniaApp()
        .StartWithClassicDesktopLifetime(args);

    // Avalonia configuration, don't remove; also used by visual designer.
    public static AppBuilder BuildAvaloniaApp()
        => AppBuilder.Configure<App>()
            .UsePlatformDetect()
            .LogToDebug()
            .UseReactiveUI()
```

Answer (score 1):

Into my App.axaml.cs i did :

```
AvaloniaLocator.CurrentMutable.BindToSelfSingleton<MyClass>();
```

if it may help.

Answer (score 0):

Avalonia is a UI framework, not MVVM framework. It doesn't provide any MVVM facilities by itself. There is, however, built-in support for ReactiveUI via `Avalonia.ReactuveUI` nuget package and [3rd-party support for Prism](https://github.com/AvaloniaCommunity/Prism.Avalonia).